# Fluid navigation background hover

Tags: css, image, navigation, hover, fluid

I'm not really sure how to explain  this but basically I want a "fluid" background image for my navigation bar. I'll try to explain it in the image below.

Does anyone know how to do this? I want to use the same image of all my navigation options to reduce the page loading time. Here's [my current page](http://www.s-hosting.nl/creepypastaindex) (also an example of what I **don't** want to happen there) Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: better do it with CSS3 box shadow. You can put inset shadow using that

Comment: I didn't even think of this, thanks!

Comment: I like SVS's solution. The only problem is adding support for IE6-9.  To do so, take a look at http://css3pie.com/ (adds support for CSS3 in IE6-9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fiddle of how to do it with CSS3

http://jsfiddle.net/Sn3p2/

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want with background images you'd need to images. One as the background of the LI element and one as the background of the A tag within the LI.

The background image within the A tag would be relatively thin and would be aligned to the right of the A tag.

Hope that helps.